# How to concat dataframe Twice inside a nested loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, nested-loops

A scraper that goes through each URL extracts price and appends to the dataframe.

The nested for loop which does the same but extracts multiple prices from same URL (if the `try:` statement is True) and concatenate with df.

Output from code below skips prices for outer loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Price'])
# Start scrapping
for url in card_link_list:
    wd.get(url)
    try:
        # Check for No element such exception element
        pack_sizes_elements =  wd.find_elements(By.XPATH , "//div[@class='_1LiCn']/div")
        for element in pack_sizes_elements:
            element.click()
            #Price
            price =   element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//span[@class ='_2j_7u']").text.strip()
            # concat with df
            data_dict = {'PRICE':price}
            df_dict = pd.DataFrame([data_dict])
            df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])
    
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Price
        price =   wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()
        # concat with df
        data_dict = {'PRICE':price}
        df_dict = pd.DataFrame([data_dict])
        df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])
```

Edit: Even after fixing indentation of last line the issue is unsolved.

**Output dataframe consist of rows only from nested loop and not the outer loop(where try: is False).**

What change needs to be done or suggest a better way to append results in a dataframe.

Comment: Question needs some clarity, maybe it seems to be a better approach to change the strategy of processing.

Comment: Output dataframe only contains rows from nested loop and not the outer loop. How to rectify this? @HedgeHog

Comment: not sure if your code looks exactly as on this question, but if it is, - the very last row with `concat` function is indented incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python is very sensitive to indentation.

your code:

```
 except NoSuchElementException:
        # Price
        price =   wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()
        # concat with df
        data_dict = {'PRICE':price}
        df_dict = pd.DataFrame([data_dict])
 df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])
```

correct indendation below, **keep an eye on the very last row**:

```
 except NoSuchElementException:
        # Price
        price =   wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()
        # concat with df
        data_dict = {'PRICE':price}
        df_dict = pd.DataFrame([data_dict])
        df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])
```

in your case `df = pd.concat([df, df_dict])` falls out from `except` scope.

Comment: Still. I'm unable to concat rows from except statement part

Comment: in this case check if your `price =   wd.find_element(By.XPATH, "//td[@data-qa ='productPrice']").text.strip()` under Except statement produces any values

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe cause is behind recreation of dict every loop or something like that.

Comment: for my level, sadly difficult to advise more as the code looks correct... maybe any other type of code after the `except` statement does something, - I would test if both statements `try` and `except` produces the same datatype, also, would save temporary `test.csv` straight after `df = pd.concat([df, df_dict]) ` in `except` section to see what is going on.

Comment: P.S. your `df` is not re-recreated during each loop, you just adding more data from `df_dict` to the bottom of it using concat.
Check indentations in other parts of the code also, - as you had such a mistake, maybe you have more.

Comment: I replaced the Nosuchelementexception with Timeoutexception and add WebDriverWait(wd, 2) presence of element detected statement. It seems to solve the issue for now, but has increased the running time significantly

Comment: u were right there is nothing wrong with code instead how the try except statements were conditioned

Comment: I am not into web scapping, but it sounds strange anyway... as you previously mentioned your `except` statement produced values, but they have not been `concat'ed` to the main `df`... So `NoSuchElementException` was triggered and the collection of the `price` value was done... I have a feeling, - it breaks somewhere else...
I should suggest to re-tag or creating a new question, so the guys with knowledge in `selenium` would pop-in